# apache camel simple expression not giving string value

Tags: java, apache-camel, simple-el

I am using apache camel. I am trying to retrieve value from body using simple expression language. I need it as a String but simple returns SimpleBuilder object. So I have tried something like this

```
simple("${body.address.line}").resultType(String.class).getResultType()
```

but it is returning me java.lang.String. please tell me how can I get this expression's result as String?

Comment: Can you show where the simple code is being used?

Comment: Try `getText()` method. [https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/SimpleBuilder.html#getText()](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/SimpleBuilder.html#getText())

Comment: @Valijon:tried it just print the same whatever written inside simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is only for configuring the simple expression. If you need to evaluate it then call the evaluate method

```
String foo = simple("${body.address.line}").evaluate(exchange, String.class);
```

Comment: Where would the exchange come from if you were doing this in a route? 

e.g. 
from('direct:start').unmarshal(simple('${in.header.datatype-ref}').evaluate(exchange??, String.class))

Comment: Same question for me. Can we make it work inside a route?

Answer (score 1):

Using xml, we can simply evaluate using

```
<simple>${body.address.line}</simple>
```