# Exchange/body reference inside the configure method of a Java DSL RouteBuilder

Tags: java, apache-camel

I haved code the following route using apache camel version 2.21.2. There is also a function I want to use to log the body.

```
Function<Object, String> returnSomethingInteresting = o -> {
    // ... compute something depending on the o class type
    return "the result based on the body";
};

@Override
public void configure() {
    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=15s") // every 15 seconds
        .setBody( Bdd.getVOs ) // I call the database to retrieve a List<MyResulSetObjectVO>
        .split().body() //split the list in its components

        .log( returnSomethingInteresting.apply( simple("${body}").evaluate(exchange, MyResulSetObjectVO.class))))     

        .to("..."); // continue the execution
}//configure
```

First I get a List of vo from the database using a Supplier. Then I split the List into its elements to process each of them separately.

But before processing them I would like to log the body of it, but not the body itselft but the result of calling a Function with the body as a parameter.

But the evaluate Expression needs the Exchange object, but I can not find a way to retrieve it. Is it there a usable reference to the exchange object from the configure method over a routeBuilder?

I know there are alternatives.

Like I can use a processor (which is process method siganture provides a exchange object) instead of a log statement. But I prefer doing it with a log because I find the code much more clear.

Or even I can insert the function inside the MyResultSetObjectVO and call it something like this. Which works fine. But that function is among a big variety of VO and I do not want to have to write it inside every VO, and whenever updating the code, copy & paste ...

```
log("${body.returnSomethingInteresting }")
```

There is a reference to the evaluate method using the exchange object in this other stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020936/apache-camel-simple-expression-not-giving-string-value?rq=1). But none of the context is mentioned so I suppose is inside a processor, which I wish not use.

Maybe I do not need to use the evaluate method, and I can get a reference to the body object, which will also fit for me.

So everything said, I would like to know how can I get a reference to the exchange/body object inside a the configure method of a camel dsl routeBuilder?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, the **configure** method is for configuring the route(s). Its only invoked **once** during startup.

As you mention you can use an inlined processor to invoke the function. The simple language can also invoke bean/methods and use bean parameter binding so it can bind data from the exchange to the bean method signature. Then you can use the simple language directly in the Log EIP.